# Is eigen-value decomposition able to be applied to any kind of matrices, if not what are the constraints?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

What are the qualifications of a matrix to have eigen-value decomposition possible?

Comment: Are you asking when a matrix is diagonalizable, or are you satisfied with decomposition of the domain to generalized eigenspaces?

Comment: 2nd is enough for me

Comment: In that case, every matrix admits such a decomposition; it's referred to as the Jordan normal form of the matrix.

Comment: @JonathanY. It depends on what base field you are working with. Every matrix admits a Jordan canonical form over $\mathbb{C}$ but not necessarily over $\mathbb{R}$. In general you need the characteristic polynomial to split.

Comment: @EuYu: yes, it seemed to me that the context of this question is thus limited, but noting that certainly doesn't hurt (although, perhaps some explanation regarding splitting fields could help make this into an answer).

Comment: As I see, every matrix has possible de composition in the complex domain but not in real domain, right ?